# Fullcalendar : Wrong end time displayed for events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, fullcalendar

I have an array of events which is here :
[image]

And this is my fullcalendar :
[image]

As you can see **the end time is never the same as the array**, but the start time is good, why?

**What I have tried :** 
timezone : local
ignoreTimeZone : true

I didn't have effects on the rendering.

*Note :* the data is fetched in my database, the date are standard DATETIME format and it is json encoded in my php file.

I think it may be because I need to parse somehow my fields but I don't know how to do it.

**this is my code :**

```
$html .= '<div id="calendar"></div>';



            // PROCEDURE SQL
            $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT id, event_titre as 'titre', event_start as 'start', event_stop as 'stop' FROM tmp;";

            //CALL WITH SESSION VARS
            if(!$mysqli->query("CALL diff('". $_SESSION['upcNameId']." ', '". $_SESSION['statDateFrom'] ." 00:00:00','". $_SESSION['statDateTo'] ." 00:00:00');"))
                die($mysqli->error);

            //EXEC SQL2
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql2)
                or die($mysqli->error);

            $i=0;
            $events = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $events[] = $row;
            }

            $buildingevents = json_encode($events);
            //echo json_encode($events);


$html .= "<script src='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/fullcalendar.css' type='text/css'>
        <script src='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/fr.js'></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var bevents = ".$buildingevents."
                console.log(bevents)
                jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                    {
                        header: {
                            right: 'today, month, agendaDay, agendaWeek, prev, next'
                        },
                        defaultDate: '" . $_SESSION['statDateFrom'] ."',
                        events: bevents,
                        timezone: 'local',
                    });
            });
        </script>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your events do not match the expected fields of an `Event` object: [see documentation here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)

Replace the aliases in your query:

`titre` by `title`

and

`stop` by `end`

and it should be good.

Comment: That was a dumb mistake sorry, thank you for your help it works now!